# Should I bring a resume to this meeting?

Tags: interviewing, resume, job-search

I am a veteran student attending a Midwestern US university.

One of the fraternities on campus has decided to seek a live in Resident Director from the veteran population, and has been coordinating with the University's Veteran Coordinator. I heard about the position from casual conversation with the Coordinator, who passed my contact info onto the fraternity's Chapter Counselor.

In his email, the Counselor stated that the fraternity is in the "final stages" of a roles/responsibilities document and are interested in my input on it, and that the University organ responsible for the building and land are "soon to complete the scholarship/grant document." He closed the email by asking when I'm available to meet.
There hasn't been a general dissemination of any job offer at the time I post this, and I know virtually nothing of what responsibilities the position would entail. Everything I do know is essentially hearsay.

Should I treat the meeting like a job interview, modifying my resume to the general requirements of a typical Resident Director position, or leave that for a latter meeting? Or should I just email the guy back and ask him directly if I should bring one?

Comment: I would be prepared for any eventuality in this case, including the need for a resume.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Should I treat the meeting like a job interview, modifying my resume to the general requirements of a typical Resident Director position, or leave that for a latter meeting?

I see no harm in **preparing in advance**, and **bring your tailored resume to the meeting**.

Best case they will ask you the resume and you will be able to hand it right there. "Worst" case, they don't ask you there for the resume, but now you already have it ready for the time they ask you for it.

In things like job-hunting, it's almost always better to prepare as much as possible, rather than under-preparing or doing things only when prompted. Preparing in advance will give you an advantage over other, non-prepared candidates.

Comment: Agree @JoeStrazzere preping includes resume, knowing what the role may be, knowing about the company, etc...